# Нужно ли выделить запятыми "в ходе данного эксперимента"? Если да, то почему?

Tags: пунктуация

*Можно сделать вывод, что в ходе эксперимента испытуемый очень долго вспоминал ответы.*

Нужно ли выделить запятыми "в ходе эксперимента", если да, то почему?

Answer (score 4):

*Запятые совершенно не нужны.* То же самое, как если бы было "во время эксперимента". Это просто обстоятельство. Возможно, в другом случае это выражение и можно было бы выделить запятыми как пояснительное, но не тогда, когда оно стоит сразу после "что".